# Is there a rule that suspend lawsuit during presidency

Tags: united-states, president

Can a president file a personal lawsuit, or he will just have to wait until his term is over? I know the president is not possible to have time for that, but legally, can he?

Similarly, does a private citizen has to wait until a president get out of office to sue him?

Comment: For the second question, no: [The supreme court ruled in 1999 that a sitting president can still be subjected to civil law suits for acts and crimes committed before taking office, or unrelated to his office.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinton_v._Jones)